# ASP.NET MVC AJAX Form Submit losing ListBoxFor/MultiSelectList on submit/post action

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My selectedActiveRoles and selectedInactiveRoles are not coming through to the controller as part of my viewmodel when submitting via Ajax and I haven't found anything addressing this specifically.  It was working fine when I was just posting the form.

My form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "editForm", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div id="dualListBoxContainer">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Available Roles:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8 input-group">
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedInactiveRoles, new MultiSelectList(Model.InactiveRoles, "RoleId", "Description", @Model.SelectedInactiveRoles), new { @class = "form-control", name = "inactiveRoles", multiple = "multiple", size = 5 })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="addRole"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i> Add </button>
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="removeRole"> Remove <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i> </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Active Roles:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8 input-group">
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedActiveRoles, new MultiSelectList(Model.ActiveRoles, "RoleId", "Description", @Model.SelectedActiveRoles), new { @class = "form-control", name = "activeRoles", multiple = "multiple", size = 5 })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 text-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveChanges">Save Changes &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Model:

```
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public User User { get; set; }
        public Client Client { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Role> ActiveRoles { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Role> InactiveRoles { get; set; }
        public IList<int> SelectedActiveRoles { get; set; }
        public IList<int> SelectedInactiveRoles { get; set; }
    }
```

JS/JQuery:

```
$('#editForm')
    .submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // modifies the 'selected' options on the list
        // before finally being submitted by the browser
        $('#SelectedInactiveRoles, #SelectedActiveRoles')
            .prop('selected', true);

        $.ajax({
            url: $("#editForm").attr('action'),
            type: 'post',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function() {

                $("#modalContainer")
                    .fadeOut(500,
                        function() {
                            $("#modalContainer").empty();
                        });
            }
        });
    });
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind] MyViewModel)
        {
              return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not sending any valid data to the controller because in `$(this).serialize(),`, `this` is the ajax request, not the form. You need to serialize the form data before the ajax call

```
$('#editForm').submit(function(e) {
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    ....
    $.ajax({
        ....
        data: formData,
        success: function() {
```

However there are numerous other issues with your code.

Your `ListBoxFor()` code should be

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedInactiveRoles, 
    new SelectList(Model.InactiveRoles, "RoleId", "Description"),
    new { @class = "form-control", size = 5 }
)
```

1. There is no point adding `multiple="multiple"` because the method
   already add it.
2. There is no point adding `name= "inactiveRoles"` because it does
   absolutely nothing - inspect the html your generating and you will
   see that its `name="SelectedInactiveRoles"`, not
   `name="inactiveRoles"` (which is fortunate otherwise you could
   override the `name` attribute which would result in model binding
   failing)
3. There is no point adding the 4th parameter when generating the
   `SelectList` - its the value of the property which determines what
   is selected (you could put whatever values you want in the 4th
   parameter and you will see that its ignored by the `ListBoxFor()`
   method)

Finally, remove `$('#SelectedInactiveRoles, #SelectedActiveRoles').prop('selected', true);` (it makes no sense and does nothing at all) and the `[Bind]` attribute from your controller method.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. I believe the SelectList element is derived from MultiSelectList. In this context, either seems to work fine.  

After incorporating your changes, I believe the issue was ultimately caused by: `$('#SelectedInactiveRoles, #SelectedActiveRoles').prop('selected', true);`

I needed to select the options within the select element: `$('#SelectedInactiveRoles option, #SelectedActiveRoles option').prop('selected', true);`

To pass in multiple values with the MultiSelectList or SelectList, you have to have something selected, otherwise it comes through as null.

Comment: Selecting your answer for thoroughness, and because the addition of `var formData = $(this).serialize();` was necessary. Thanks!

Comment: Did you also have some other javascript where you were trying to move options from one listbox to another? (If that was the case, then you should consider re-thinking this and go for a checked list box UI instead)

Comment: Ah, yeah -- I included only items that were relevant to the form submission.  I have the two list boxes, active and inactive, and buttons which move between the two and allow for multi-select.  Will look into the checked list box as an alternative as well.